# Can I setup VirtualHost with same Domain name and same Port

Tags: apache, symfony, virtualhost, httpd.conf

AS topic, does my I idea come to true
I need to define the DocumentRoot, ErrorLog and RedirectMatch for my symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly you want to define more than one vhost using same port and domain-name combination?! If they differ by IP that's possible, if not, well, it's not.

But I don't assume that you have several IPs reserved for one name?! In most cases you also shouldn't! Vhost is the way to go here, BUT

```
domain1+port1 != domain2+port2
```

So either the port or the name has to be different.